# How to get users from Active Directory in C# and display them in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to show, in a `ComboBox` control, the users from an Active Directory on the network. To do this, I've the next function:

```
public static List<Usuario> MostrarUsuariosDominio()
    {
        List<Usuario> rst = new List<Usuario>();

        try
        {

            DirectoryContext dc = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);
            Domain domain = Domain.GetDomain(dc);
            DirectoryEntry de = domain.GetDirectoryEntry();

            DirectorySearcher adSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(de); 

            adSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
            adSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");

            SearchResult result;
            SearchResultCollection iResult = adSearcher.FindAll();

            Usuario item;
            if (iResult != null)
            {
                for (int counter = 0; counter < iResult.Count; counter++)
                {
                    result = iResult[counter];
                    if (result.Properties.Contains("samaccountname"))
                    {
                        item = new Usuario();

                        item.Nombre = (String)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0];

                        rst.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            adSearcher.Dispose();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Usuario item = new Usuario();
            item.Nombre = "No se pudo recuperar la lista de usuarios";
            rst.Add(item);
        }

        return rst;
    }
```

If I run the application in the PC who's domain controller it works fine: the function returns to me all users. But if I run it on another PC, I get the exception:

> Specified domain does not exist or couldn't contact with it

Is there any way to recover the users list from another PC?

Comment: Launching a VPN does not mean you are automaticalle connected to the domain. Have rou tried to run the executable file explicitly under a domain user (right click -> run as other user -> enter domain info)?

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
DirectoryContext dc = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);
```

Tells it to connect to the domain that the current user is logged into. Are you logged in as a domain user?

Maybe check what `Environment.UserDomainName` is equal to and see if it is right.

If it's right, then it may be a network issue - it can't talk to the domain. Do you need to be connected to VPN?

Comment: No much info on the OP regarding the computer being in the domain or whenever it is run under a domain account. This answer helps to check those potential problems :-)

Comment: I've noticed that the PC I tested is another server with a local user. As soon I can I'll try on a workstation and I'll post the result.

Thank's :)

Comment: You could just specify the domain name, rather than trying to infer it from the current user.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the users in a Active Directory domain you can use an `DirectorySearcher` class object to querie to a domain about all the users availables in that domain.

The class `DirectorySearcher` is contained in `System.DirectoryServices` namespace and is a class to perform queries against Active Directory Domain Services.

> **In this [page](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/599697/get-list-of-active-directory-users-in-csharp) is an example about how to do it:**
>
> ```
> ...
> string DomainPath = "LDAP://DC=xxxx,DC=com"
> DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath); 
> DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
> search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
> search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
> search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
> search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("usergroup");
> search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");//first name
> SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();
> ...
> ```
>
> In DirectorySearcher, create a DirectorySearcher object which searches
>   for all users in a domain. `search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"` filters the search.
>
> The search filter syntax looks a bit complicated, but basically it
>   filters the search results to only include users -> `"objectCategory=person"` and `"objectClass=user"` - and excludes disabled
>   user accounts by performing a bitwise AND of the userAccountControl
>   flags and the "account disabled" flag.

To point to the local Active Directory domain you can use this:

```
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName);
```

You can combine that example with this code that uses `foreach` instead of use the `for` loop in the page example:

```
foreach (SearchResult result in resultCol)
{
    yourComboBox.Items.Add(result.Properties["displayname"]);
}
```

I left here some pages from the Microsoft MSDN and codeproject.com sites:

[DirectorySearcher Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Get List of Active Directory Users in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/599697/get-list-of-active-directory-users-in-csharp)

[SearchResultCollection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresultcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

[SearchResult Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult(v=vs.110).aspx)

[SearchResult.Properties Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult.properties(v=vs.110).aspx)